# Design discussion: store serialized class or create specific table?

Tags: database, oop, database-design, serialization

I want to store info from an specific class ("MyClass") in a **database**. So, I got **two options**:

1. **Serialize object** (class MyClass) and store it as a binary field in my **existing** table.
2. **Create a new table** containing as many fields as MyClass contains.

Which is the best approach?
I am concerned about changing MyClass definition in the future. So, if MyClass changes, I will no be able to deserialize binary object from my existing table. In the other hand, creating a new table seems to be more complex and also it is necessary to modify table definition when MyClass changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persist your class in a table with a column per property.  This gives you a lot more control and will save you writing a lot of code, since database engines are designed specifically for reading and writing data.

Think about this: If you use serialization, how are you going to retrieve data about a group of rows that match a particular search value?  The only way is to read each row, deserialize it, test your search condition, and move on to the next record until you've read all of them.

With a database you just specify a `WHERE` clause and you get exactly the rows you're looking for.  In the background, a lot of the same kind of work (may) be going on, but it's all being done by code **you didn't have to write** or maintain.